# IBM MobileFirst Appcenter - How to update application details added from public appstore (Google play Or Apple store)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I am using the MobileFirst platform 6.3 appcenter. I am able to add applications from public app stores such as Google Play or Apple App Store by entering their URLs. While adding application, Appcenter automatically fetches all the information like version, icon, description, vendor etc.

Once application added, these details remains as it is until someone changes it manually from appcenter admin console.

Is there anyway to update external application details automatically in the appcenter? Or is there any third party tool available which I can use for updating details?

Answer (score 1):

You will have the click the APP from the AppCenter console and click Apply/OK to update the properties.

Comment: Is there anyway to update application details without going to appcenter console?